# how to bring the list I created in class as a parameter in new function

Tags: python, list, function, class, parameters

I'd like to say my English is second language and sorry for any inconvenience to read or understand my post.

I will explain what kind of code I produced first,
So I created my class function using the code below

```
class Histogram:
  def __init__(self, range , max_mark):
    self.__range = range 
    self.__max_mark = max_mark
    self.__occurrence_list = [0] * self.__range
  def get_range(self):
    return self.__range
  def set_range(self, value):
    self.__range = value
  def get_max_mark(self):
    return self.__max_mark
  def set_max_mark(self, value):
    self.__max_mark = value
  def get_occurrence_list(self):
    return self.__occurrence_list
  def append_marks(self, value):
    if value > self.__max_mark:
        return 'value should be bigger than max mark'
    else:
        new = self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1
```

And What I want to do is printing a new strings by using the list which I got from the code below.

For example, 
If I put

```
a1 = Histogram(10, 9)
a1.append_marks(8)
print(a1.get_occurrence_list())
```

the result is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Now, I want to create a string which shows index number and how many numbers they have.

For example,
the given list shows 0 in each index but not in index 8

So I would like to create..

```
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
...
8: 1
9: 0
```

Something like this.

So now I have a question,

But if I introduce new function which I would say 'get_string()' and using two parameters, which would be 'self' and other value.

How can I recall the list I've got from the last to the new function?
What would be the code after

```
def get_string(self, other):
```

If I want to create something like the string above?

Comment: ***"How can I recall the list I've got from the*** **LAST** ***to the*** **NEW** ***function?...If I want to create something like the string above?"*** Could you, please, expatiate a little bit.... which is the last function, which is the new function... a little explicitness could help....

Answer (score 0):

Your object's property will be available in your new method. Code below should print your list as you described.

```
for index, item in self.__occurrence_list.enumerate():
    print (str(index) + ':' + str(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to revisit the Method, `append_marks(self, value)`. Ideally that Method should have read:

```
def append_marks(self, value):
    if value > self.__max_mark:
        return 'value should be bigger than max mark'
    else:
        # YOU SHOULDN'T DO new = self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1 
        # RATHER JUST DO: self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1
        self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1
        # new = self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1 #<= WITHOUT new =...
```

The `get_string()` Method could be implemented thus:

```
def get_string(self):
    outString   = ""
    if self.__occurrence_list:
        for key, val in enumerate(self.__occurrence_list):
            outString += str(key) + ":" + str(val)  + "\n"
    return outString
```

Thus your Class could look something like this:

```
class Histogram:
    def __init__(self, range , max_mark):
        self.__range = range
        self.__max_mark = max_mark
        self.__occurrence_list = [0] * self.__range

    def get_range(self):
        return self.__range

    def set_range(self, value):
        self.__range = value

    def get_max_mark(self):
        return self.__max_mark

    def set_max_mark(self, value):
        self.__max_mark = value

    def get_occurrence_list(self):
        return self.__occurrence_list

    def append_marks(self, value):
        if value > self.__max_mark:
            return 'value should be bigger than max mark'
        else:
            self.__occurrence_list[value] += 1

    def get_string(self):
        outString   = ""
        if self.__occurrence_list:
            for key, val in enumerate(self.__occurrence_list):
                outString += str(key) + ":" + str(val)  + "\n"
        return outString




a1  = Histogram(10, 9)
a1.append_marks(8)
a1.append_marks(8)
a1.append_marks(8)
a1.append_marks(8)
a1.append_marks(8)
a1.append_marks(8)

print(a1.get_occurrence_list())
print(a1.get_string())
```

[image: Test Screenshot]